# Determining the role of "to" in these sentences

Tags: grammar

This situation has been confusing me for a long time, and I can't define the difference in the meaning of them. For instance:

> I suddenly realized this is going to be far more fulfilling if I spent my life creating mazes.

I wonder may I use that one by another way, like:

> I suddenly realized this is going to be far more fulfilling if I spent my life to create mazes.

Comment: thats actually what i need,wish i had known this site earlier :)